# installing ubuntu replacing windows 7 on my pc

Tags: 12.04, installation, drivers

i wanted to ask that whether installing ubuntu replacing windows 7 on my pc, erases the files on the other drives or only removes the file from the C drive in which i have my system files? and would i need to download special softwares for proper running of ubuntu? and what about the sund card and audio drivers?please help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have the freedom to dual boot your machine (Meaning running two or more operating systems). At the start of the ubuntu installation,you will be asked whether you want ubuntu to run along side windows (Dual boot) or run ubuntu as your sole OS. If you want to replace Windows 7 with ubuntu,I would back up all Music,pictures, and important data to an external source. As this WILL ERASE everything on your HDD.

Second, I would not worry about drivers. At installation, you will need internet. You can plug in an ethernet, or if you don't have an ethernet cable there is a workaround I found to be useful. At boot of the media you have ubuntu on select "Try Ubuntu" and try it out for a while. Under "System settings" select "Additional drivers" and click activate. when it's done activating. close out and double click "Install ubuntu".

At the installation prompt I would tick "Install updates" and "Install codecs" so you can play Mp3 filesand grab ALL drivers you need.

Welcome to ubuntu and enjoy, if you need more assistance we are all here, and happy to help.

-FoxyRK9